# how to disable browser autofill username and password. we are using Gwt MVP model for creating screen and using Sencha GXT library

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

we have autocomplete="off" in jquery but not finding to set in gwt xml file.Can someone help me to set autocomplete to false.

```
<f:FieldLabel labelSeparator="" ui:field="userNameLabel">
<f:widget><f:TextField width="300" ui:field="userName" /></f:widget>
</f:FieldLabel>
```

Textfield doesn't have autocomplete attribute to set.

Comment: Is this a UiBinder .ui.xml file you are refering to?  There is an answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018822/gwt-uibinder-autocorrect-off

Comment: yes.but we are using TextField  not textbox @RobertNewton

Comment: Nowhere in your question have you mentioned what GWT UI library you are using.  The answer below asked you this question and you didn't say.  Do you want help or not?

Comment: what about adding the "gxt" or "gwt-ext" tag so that experts in GXT will see your question and possibly help you?  At the moment you only have the "gwt" tag.

Answer (score 1):

What ui library are you using?

For example if you are using vanilla gwt you could get the Element and set the attribute autocomplete="off"  manually

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

You could create a Composite that wraps the field and set this automatically, then create instances of TextFieldNotAutocomplete for example

http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html

Comment: I tried by setting autocomplete="off" but not working